# Prove that $\{x \in X : f(x) \leq g(x)\}$ is a closed set

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a set with a total order, and with the order topology. Let $X$ be a topological space and $f,g:X \longrightarrow Y$ be two continuous functions. I want to prove that the set
$$\{x \in X : f(x) \leq g(x)\}$$
is a closed set of $X$. I know that this will happen if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ is a closed set of $Y$ (because the pre-image of a closed set by a continuous function is a closed set).
I know that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ is well defined since $Y$ is a set with a total order. However, the fact that I have $\leq$ instead of $<$ creates sets in $Y$ where the opposite ends are included, and I don't know how to handle this.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3857242/order-topology-continuous-functions)?

Comment: Consider the complementary set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach might be incorrect. Your statement that "$f(x) \le g(x)$ is a closed set of $Y$" actually does not make any sense, because $f(x) \le g(x)$ is not a set, and I can't really see how to re-interpret your statement in a reasonable way.

We want to prove a statement that a given subset of $X$ is closed, but we have no idea what the topology of $X$ is. That's where we need the continuity of $f$ and $g$ - by taking pre-image of open sets of $Y$, we can obtain open sets in $X$, and use those open sets to prove what we need.

The set $A = \{ x : f(x) \le g(x) \}$ has complement $B = \{ x : f(x) > g(x) \}$. We show $B$ is open by writing it as a union of open sets $B = B' \cup B''$.

Let $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) > g(x_0)$.

**Case 1:** There exists a $y$ in $Y$ such that $f(x_0) > y > g(x_0)$. Then from definitions one can check that $x_0 \in B'$, where
$$ B' = \bigcup_{y \in Y} \Big( \{ x : f(x) > y \} \cap \{ x : g(x) < y \} \Big) $$
and $B'$ is a union of open sets, and hence is open.

**Case 2:** There does not exist a $y$ in $Y$ such that $f(x_0) > y > g(x_0)$. Then observe that
$$x_0 \in \{ x : f(x) > g(x_0) \} \cap \{ x : g(x) < f(x_0) \} \subseteq \{x : f(x) > g(x) \}$$

Let $B''$ be the collection of all $x_0 \in X$, such that case 2 occurs. That is,
$$ B'' = \bigcup_{x_0} \; \{ x : f(x) > g(x_0) \} \cap \{ x : g(x) < f(x_0) \}$$
where the union is taken over all $x_0$ such that there does not exist a $y \in Y$ satisfying $f(x_0) > y > g(x_0)$. Then $B''$ is a union of open sets, hence is open.

Then $B = B' \cup B''$ is an open set, as desired.

Comment: @kubo There might be a small problem with the way I wrote $B$ as a union - because if $Y$ is discrete set, even if $f(x) > g(x)$ for some $x$, there might not be a $y \in Y$ with $f(x) > y > g(x)$. Let me think about it and get back to you.

Comment: Maybe you can use that the order topology is always Hausdorff? I don't really know how to formalize this but it might be useful

Comment: @kubo I have fixed the proof. It is a lot uglier than I would like but I can't think of any other way to do it :(

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach:

Let $\varphi:\Lambda\to Y=\{x\in X:f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ be a net. Suppose $\varphi$ converges in $X$, say, $\varphi(\lambda)\to x_0$. Since $f,g$ are both continuous, and $f(\varphi(\lambda))\leq g(\varphi(\lambda))$ holds for all $\lambda\in \Lambda$, by taking limit we have $f(x_0)\leq g(x_0)$, which finishes the proof.

What I used in this proof:

1, $Y\subseteq X$ is closed iff it is closed under limit.

2, $f$ is continuous iff for every $\varphi(\lambda)\to x_0$, there is $f(\varphi(\lambda))\to f(x_0)$.

3, For $\varphi(\lambda)\to x_0$, if $\varphi(\lambda)\leq y_0$($\varphi(\lambda)\geq y_0$) holds for every $\lambda$, then $x_0\leq y_0$($x_0\geq y_0$). Thus $\leq $ is 'continuous'.

The definition of convergence here is, $ \varphi(\lambda)\to x$ iff for every neighborhood $O_x\ni x$ there is some $\lambda_0\in \Lambda$ such that $\varphi(\{\lambda\geq \lambda_0\})\subseteq O_x$.

1 and 2 are fundamental facts. Let me prove 3. Assume $x_0>y_0$, then $\{x>y_0\}$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$, so by convergence there is $\lambda$ such that $\varphi(\lambda)>y_0$, which is a contradiction.